# Original error: Bad app: App paths need to be absolute or an URL to a compressed app file:

Tags: python, ios, xcode, appium, ios-simulator

[image]

I want to open demo app using appium (in ios simulator using X code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring a `.swift` file instead of `.app` file. Try writing this

```
"appium:app": "/Users/pritwindersingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-bpndfqzifmteusepnbmywejsnvgw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntegrationApp.app"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring a `.swift` file instead of app.
Changing it to "app": "/path/to/my.app" might work.